# Expresso Store : Storing data within the exp_store_order_items table

Tags: expresso-store

I just wanted to check if I'm missing something here. Is there anyway to store custom data against an order item - for example, I have a set of sessions (think events) and I would like to store details against the specific session they've booked. Something like the name, address of the person attending the session.

This data may be different from the billing details, and the customer who purchases maybe purchasing multiple sessions for different people. I think the order items table is where this should come (or join) from.

I understand this is fairly edge case, but wanted to check I wasn't re-inventing some functionality before I crack out the extension generator...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `order_customX` fields 1-9 to store custom data about the order (and/or can be linked to custom member fields to repopulate the fields in future orders). You would do this via the checkout tag ([docs here](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#custom_order_fields)).

Depending on the amount of data that you are collecting this could not be enough fields for the information that you need to store. In the past when I am selling event type tickets I add the custom data to the product using text modifiers set at the template level so I can easily include them outside of the publisher area for any and all events. For this approach you would add the additional details when you are adding the item to the cart via the product tag ([docs here](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html#input_custom_modifier_name_name)).